# Android multitaksing

Tags: android, multitasking

I am seeking short characteristic of Android Multitasking. I have found, that when you minimize Android application, it is ended and it's process remains on the background. When user wants to reuse his app, this process alive it's application. User will be at the same state, when he left (if there was enough memory while working with it), or it will be loaded from scratch, because there was no free RAM for other work and Android exited this process. Am I right? Everywhere there are articles with 20 pages and more about Android multitaksing. I need to know key points because I am lost in a such long artices.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer:** Yes. If your app can live in memory despite being 'closed' then it will stay in RAM and processing will continue when you click on it again. Otherwise it will be restarted and you will get an onResume().

**Long Answer:** Please just read the [Activity Lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/activities.html#Lifecycle):[image]

Answer (score 1):

When Android activity is covered by other windows it will enter into paused state and method `onPause` will be called. It may also me destroyed by OS and then `onDestroy` will be called. You have very little control over it and can't expect your application to come back up with the same state. However, when activity is brought up again to foreground in will go through steps of `onCreate` and `onPause`. Those methods can be used to restore its state.

Here you can find nice diagrams describing Activity lifecycle. Similar but slightly different lifecycle is applicable to service.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 1):

Android activities are the main visible screens that user see while the application is running.  If you close the screen or switch to another application, the current activity is put to hibernate and you can save the state with

[Activity.onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

After your activity gets the control back, you can restore the state with

[Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle bundle)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestoreInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29)

Note that you need to be careful not to store any context references within the activities and related classes as the activity and thus context has changed between pause and resume.  Instead, you should always pass the current activity as the active context to avoid having exceptions from invalid context.